# UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync vs SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

using asp net core identity - when user provides password and username to get a jwt token they post credentials to /api/token

should my token controller method be using usermanager to check the password using the CheckPasswordAsync and if this passes return the token or should i use the signinmanager and call PasswordSignInAsync and then return token based on that result?

I have seen examples of both and wondered what is benefit of each, is one way better than the other?

Currently someone in my team has written the following:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<User>> Post([FromBody]User model)
{
    try
    {                                              
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);
        if (user == null)
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized, "Incorrect username or password");

        var passwordOK = await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (!passwordOK)
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized, "Incorrect username or password");

        model.Id = user.Id;
        model.Name = user.DisplayName;
        model.Password = "";               

        int expiresIn;
        long expiresOn;
        model.Token = _authorisationService.GetJWTToken(model.Username, user.Id, out expiresIn, out expiresOn);
        model.ExpiresIn = expiresIn;
        model.ExpiresOn = expiresOn;

        return model;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // log the exception
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
    }
}
```

but i think there are things in that that are not necessary.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The two methods you've mentioned serve different purposes:

#### 1. UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync

This method hashes the provided password and compares it against the existing password hash (stored in the database, for example).

#### 2. SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync

This method *does a lot more*. Here's a rough breakdown:

- Checks whether sign-in is allowed. For example, if the user must have a confirmed email before being allowed to sign-in, the method returns `SignInResult.Failed`.
- Calls `UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync` to check that the password is correct (as detailed above).

  - If the password is not correct and lockout is supported, the method tracks the failed sign-in attempt. If the configured amount of failed sign-in attempts is exceeded, the method locks the user out.
- If two-factor authentication is enabled for the user, the method sets up the relevant cookie and returns `SignInResult.TwoFactorRequired`.
- Finally, performs the sign-in process, which ends up creating a `ClaimsPrincipal` and persisting it via a cookie.

If you are not interested in requiring confirmed emails, lockout, etc, then using `UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync` as in your question will suffice.

Comment: ok thanks after researching a bit more the signinmanger is tied in to the cookie auth so in my case if i dont want to use cookies then according to the github identity source i should avoid signinmanager.  In that case to have features such as lockout etc in my cookie-less api i would need to implement these features myself.

Comment: @JimmyShoe Do you have sample code to share, or a link for an example implementation? I'm also using JWT (instead of cookies) and am surprised how hard it is to find such code.

Comment: `UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync` does one other thing: It logs a warning if the password is incorrect.  Annoying because it clutters up the log with warnings for a normal event (we expect users to occasionally mistype passwords).

Comment: Is PasswordSignInAsync supported in .NET Framework 4.6.2?

Answer (score 0):

My simple take on it was that I needed to still use SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync for enhanced features it offers but didn't want it calling IsTwoFactorClientRememberedAsync as that creates an authentication cookie (my specific use case is to wrap ASP.NET Core Identity in a REST API facade for architectural reasons).

So, I simply created a custom class which derives from SignInManager and specifically overrides the `Task<SignInResult> CheckPasswordSignInAsync(TUser user, string password, bool lockoutOnFailure)` method, allowing me to effectively re-implement the method exactly as it appears in the original source (https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/Core/src/SignInManager.cs) but *without* the call to IsTwoFactorClientRememberedAsync.

Seems to work OK for me.