# How to get the bearer token using Microsoft Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have created a controller for Login and there is an endpoint for authentication. I am using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;`

[image]

Here is the code for this controller

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Security.Claims;

[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class LoginController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;

        public LoginController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> LoginAsync([FromBody] LoginRequest userLogin)
        {         
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(userLogin.Username, userLogin.Password, isPersistent: false, lockoutOnFailure: false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                 // code removed for brevity                   
                }               
            }
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
```

How do I get the bearer token from `result`? I wish to return back the token bearer as a response if /api/Login post request is successful.

Comment: PasswordSignInAsync doesn't appear to return anything related to a bearer token. Can you link the documentation on the token you're trying to get?

Comment: Your question needs more detail as far as what you are trying to accomplish.  PasswordSignInAsync won't give you anything automatically.  If you want to use tokens for subsequent API calls after login, check this article:  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/bearer-token-authentication-in-asp-net-core/ Otherwise, please be more specific about what the entire process should do and what technologies and packages are being used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SignInManager<TUser>.PasswordSignInAsync` Method Attempts to sign in the specified userName and password combination as an asynchronous operation and return `Task<SignInResult>`. for bearer token use `CheckPasswordAsync`.
its return a flag indicating whether the given password is valid for the specified user.

```
_userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password)
```

if user has valid creadintial then [generate the token](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/jwt-token-authentication-and-authorizations-in-net-core-6-0-web-api/).

```
            if (user != null && await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password))
            {
                var userRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

                var authClaims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                };

                foreach (var userRole in userRoles)
                {
                    authClaims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userRole));
                }

               var token = GetToken(authClaims);

                return Ok(new
                {
                    token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
                    expiration = token.ValidTo
                });
            }
```

Ref: [Link1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1.passwordsigninasync?view=aspnetcore-6.0), [Link2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinresult?view=aspnetcore-6.0), [Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53854051/usermanager-checkpasswordasync-vs-signinmanager-passwordsigninasync), [Link4](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/jwt-token-authentication-and-authorizations-in-net-core-6-0-web-api/)

Answer (score 0):

Depending how you want the client to store the token. If you want to deal with it in the client side you can `Return Ok(result.generatedToken)` but if you want to set it as a cookie I would recommend you to just Return Ok() but before that you set the cookie in the header of the response. You do this in the server

```
 // append cookie with token to the http response
        CookieOptions? cookieOptions = new()
        {
            HttpOnly = true,
            SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict,
            Secure = true,
            Expires = ExpirationDate //it has to be a DateTime
        };
        Response.Cookies.Append("token", token, cookieOptions);
```

the advantage of doing it from the server is that you protect the token from being stolen by XSS injection or other attacks since the token is not accessable from javascript and can only be used in HTTPrequests.

Answer (score 0):

If you can update your project to asp.net core 8 best solution will be using [Identity API endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-8.0). This is an identity endpoint example. If you still want to keep your implementation on top of asp.net core identity this example has complete extendable code with react. [Source](https://github.com/andissanayake/UnifiedApp) [Tutorial](https://medium.com/@disa2aka/token-authentication-asp-net-1e7fdfb838bb)