# Where does the SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync store the user data?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-mvc

I am looking at a project that is using .NET Identity, and having the following code in the login action method:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return View(model);
}

// Require the user to have a confirmed email before they can log on.
var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
if (user != null)
{
   if (!await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id))
   {
      ViewBag.errorMessage = "You must have a confirmed email to log on.";
      return View("Error");
   }
}

// This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
// To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
switch (result)
{
    case SignInStatus.Success:
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
        return View("Lockout");
    case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
        return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
    case SignInStatus.Failure:
    default:
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
        return View(model);
}
```

The database is SQL server.

I believe that `var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);` is responsible to set the cookie and send it into the response to the browser. Then, in the subsequent requests, the browser will send that cookie for the Authentication middleware to be able to set the User principal/identity/claims. Therefore no repeated access to the database is required to get the user role/other details (claims).

This question is to ask - what exactly is stored in the cookie? Does the cookie contain the encrypted key that refers to some values stored on the server (if yes then where is this store)? or does the cookie hold encrypted username, claims?

For example:

1. Client side cookie
2. Server side session state, with client side cookie only containing the encrypted sessionid

Comment: could this case answer your question？https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53854051/usermanager-checkpasswordasync-vs-signinmanager-passwordsigninasync